# DataBinding with dependency property in wpf

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have 2 windows w1 and w2 with one textbox each and data in txtbox1 in w1 needs to be appearing in w2 txtbox  .How to achieve this using dependency properties

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you rather use a common DataContext for your two windows than binding them to each other. As an example, let's assume you have this class as DataModel:

```
public class MyDataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string text;

    public string Text {
        get { return text; }
        set {
            text = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can set it as DataContext on your windows:

```
MyDataModel model = new MyDataModel();
model.Text = "Hello World";

MyWindow a = new MyWindow();
MyOtherWindow b = new MyOtherWindow();
a.DataContext = model;
b.DataContext = model;
```

If you have done this, you can set the Text Property of the TextBoxes in every window to a Binding like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"/>
```

Both Textboxes will now automatically update if you set model.Text to another value.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a mother of the 2 forms? a form that creates both of them?

In this case what I normally do, since I'm implementing `INotifyOnPropertyChanged` anyway, is in the mother I subscribe to the w1's `PropertyChanged` event, get the value, and then place it in the property of w2.

I wouldnt really use Dependency Properties

I know its not pretty but I generally prefer it because I like to keep the 1 viewmodel to 1 view relationship. My boss thinks its easier to read and understand this way.